# Ho Do I Add A Link To The Blog's Homepage To The Admin Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently my Wordpress theme has a link to the Blog root page in the Admin top menu, however I would like a link in the Admin Sidebar below 'Dashboard' and 'Profile'.

I have tried adding it using

```
add_menu_page( 'Course', 'Course', 'read', get_option('home'), 'home', 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more')
```

This generates a link with the correct icon, however the url generated for the link is:

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin.php?page=http:/localhost:8888
```

How should I set this up to generate a link to:

```
http:/localhost:8888
```

Comment: show the code of `home` function ..

Answer (score 0):

`add_menu_page` adds a new menu item page to Wordpress admin menu. It can't have link as it doesn't accepts that as a parameter. But, we can redirect in the custom callback function.

[Updated Code/]

This is the full implementation:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page');

function register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('Course', 'Course', 'read', get_option('home'), 'redirect_to_local_110', 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
}

function redirect_to_local_110() {
    //hardcode URL
    $url = "http://localhost:8888";
    //OR 
    //If URL has to be the Home URL then it can be fetched using
    //$url = get_option('home');
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$url.'" />';
    exit;
}
```

I also have update the redirect to meta, because using wp_redirect usually causes headers already sent error, and the cause of the error is that the output is started before this function gets called.

Comment: Thanks, but this redirects to the same URL: `http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin.php?page=http:/localhost:8888`